# Azure DevOps REST API top parameter in PowerShell script is not working

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, rest, azure-devops-rest-api

I have below script to generate releases report from Azure DevOps project.

```
$token="**************************************************************"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgnization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

Foreach($projectName in $response.value.name)
{
  
  $url1="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{orgnization}/$($projectname)/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0"
 
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json-patch

  
   echo $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 |  Out-File "D:\\file.json" -Append

}
```

In this script the first API is returning just 100 record. When I tried to add top parameter to return more record like below, it is not returing anything. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
https://dev.azure.com/uniperteamservices/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0&$top=500
```

Can you suggest how can I add top parameter in REST API url which can run in my above PowerShell script?

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to escape the `$` in the query string, otherwise PowerShell will try to inject the value of whatever variable called `top` holds:

```
$urlBase="...?api-version=6.0&`$top=5"
                              ^^^^^
```

`$top=` has been tricky at times. It may or may not give you the requested number of items, it seems to depend on how busy the backend is. But it does promise you this: All of the REST API's will return a `x-ms-continuation-token` header next to the payload and you can use this to fetch the next batch of items:

[image]

You can fetch the next batch of projects by requesting the exact same REST query and adding the `&continuationtoken=${ms-continuation-token}` query parameter to the call. Repeat this until the server stops sending the `x-ms-continuation-token` header, which signifies you've gotten all the values you were after.

You can grab the headers by passing in a second variable:

```
$urlBase="https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0&`$top=5"

$url = $urlBase
$results = @();

do 
{
    write-host "Calling API"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json -ResponseHeadersVariable headers
    $results += $response.value

    if ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])
    {
        $continuation = $headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"]
        write-host "Token: $continuation"
        $url = $urlBase + "&continuationtoken=" + $continuation
    }
} while ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])

$results
```

Will show:

```
Calling API
Token: 5
Calling API
Token: 10
Calling API

id             : 06cb494c-b535-4f16-9323-bd0f63c38163
name           : CMMI
url            : https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/06cb494c-b535-4f16-9323-bd0f63c38163
state          : wellFormed
revision       : 414360096
visibility     : private
lastUpdateTime : 08/07/2019 20:19:09

id             : 88a7ca79-b5c8-41d2-99e7-a5578a1df424
name           : BattleJSip
description    : Battleship case in JS/TS
url            : https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/88a7ca79-b5c8-41d2-99e7-a5578a1df424
state          : wellFormed
revision       : 414360059
visibility     : private
lastUpdateTime : 15/04/2018 13:43:44

... for 12 projects
```

In case of the `/projects` endpoint the continuation token takes on a predictable value of the number of projects to skip. Other API's may return a GUID or a base64 encoded string or the ID of the last returned item. Make no assumptions about the contents of the token, always copy it from the header and put it into the next request verbatim.

e.g.

```
https://dev.azure.com/p/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0&$top=5

x-ms-continuation-token:5

{"count":5,"value":[{"id":"06cb494c-b535-4f16-9323-bd0f63c38163","name":"CMMI","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/06cb494c-b535-4f16-9323-bd0f63c38163","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360096,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2019-07-08T20:19:09.333Z"},{"id":"88a7ca79-b5c8-41d2-99e7-a5578a1df424","name":"BattleJSip","description":"Battleship case in JS/TS","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/88a7ca79-b5c8-41d2-99e7-a5578a1df424","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360059,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2018-04-15T13:43:44Z"},{"id":"f5ffbb7d-11bc-4e2f-93e0-e9ee8151b428","name":"CodeToCloud-Workshop","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/f5ffbb7d-11bc-4e2f-93e0-e9ee8151b428","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360127,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2020-10-01T18:21:03.913Z"},{"id":"6d4b20e3-4afc-4fb0-9dc9-f4b1d3ff150d","name":"Agile2017","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/6d4b20e3-4afc-4fb0-9dc9-f4b1d3ff150d","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360110,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2019-10-09T11:52:58.767Z"},{"id":"2031f1a3-c549-46f1-8c55-74390077a606","name":"jessehouwing.net","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/2031f1a3-c549-46f1-8c55-74390077a606","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360067,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2018-07-02T11:08:39.76Z"}]}
```

And then the next call

```
https://dev.azure.com/p/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0&$top=5&continuationToken=5

x-ms-continuation-token:10

{"count":5,"value":[{"id":"a88536a2-a889-45a3-a955-ddf1af8aeba1","name":"azure-devops-extensions","description":"This projects hosts the pipelines for all my Azure DevOps marketplace extensions.","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/a88536a2-a889-45a3-a955-ddf1af8aeba1","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360082,"visibility":"public","lastUpdateTime":"2019-06-28T09:48:16.943Z"},{"id":"a1627c96-8627-41c7-9c29-498d523517e0","name":"Agile","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/a1627c96-8627-41c7-9c29-498d523517e0","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360119,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2019-12-02T12:11:23.863Z"},{"id":"a57ce751-1dcc-4089-b850-359624e92977","name":"Torpydo","description":"Battleship case in Python","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/a57ce751-1dcc-4089-b850-359624e92977","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360038,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2017-11-19T19:06:20.23Z"},{"id":"73711003-5adb-4e06-a7bb-f1d12b29db42","name":"Actual Scrum","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/73711003-5adb-4e06-a7bb-f1d12b29db42","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360069,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2019-04-09T19:26:38.877Z"},{"id":"9c643486-32f0-44f5-a49b-900b72f8219b","name":"Test","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/9c643486-32f0-44f5-a49b-900b72f8219b","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360078,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2019-05-27T09:58:21.247Z"}]}
```

Will fetch projects 6 to 10 and sends a `continuation-token` back with the value 10 for the next call.

Until the `x-ms-continuation-token` header is no longer returned

```
https://dev.azure.com/p/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0&$top=5&continuationToken=10

{"count":2,"value":[{"id":"6484ebc3-af16-4af9-aa66-6b3398db7214","name":"demo","description":"This team is  meant to be used for all kinds of great demos","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/6484ebc3-af16-4af9-aa66-6b3398db7214","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360040,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2018-02-08T04:57:49.15Z"},{"id":"c3eb1420-aa31-4610-9bb1-30b9e3496967","name":"OhhShitGit","url":"https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects/c3eb1420-aa31-4610-9bb1-30b9e3496967","state":"wellFormed","revision":414360050,"visibility":"private","lastUpdateTime":"2018-03-13T10:41:22.567Z"}]}
```

Blogged: [Accessing Azure DevOps APIs with large volumes of data](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-accessing-apis-with-large-volumes-of-data/)

Comment: Hi jessehouwing, Thanks for your response but I am not sure how it can be accommodated in my PowerShell script because I am not expert in that. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Nice detail in the response. To Jesse's initial point, it's been my experience that `$top` will not work unless it's explicitly called out in the endpoint documentation (and even then the implementation leaves a bit to be desired). It would definitely be nice to have a little more control over the "page" size, but I do think that `ms-continuation-token` is the best you're going to get for some endpoints. Certainly the most consistent.