# Why the max count is 1000 for the results -> list API in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have more than 1000 test cases in my test run and I want to get results by

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0
```

API, but in the response, I get a `count: 1000`, how can I get the right count?

Answer (score 3):

For performance reasons Azure DevOps limits the amount of data it returns in a single API call. Where possible use a Query do reduce the amount of data you retrieve, but you really need all of them, you can use the paging/continuation token features to fetch all of the data in more than one request.

Here is an [example on how to do that from PowerShell.](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-accessing-apis-with-large-volumes-of-data/)

```
# Change top=5 below to 100 or so depending on your use case.
$urlBase="https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0&`$top=5"

$url = $urlBase
$results = @();

do 
{
    write-host "Calling API"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json -ResponseHeadersVariable headers
    $results += $response.value

    if ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])
    {
        $continuation = $headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"]
        write-host "Token: $continuation"
        $url = $urlBase + "&continuationToken=" + $continuation
    }
} while ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])

$results
```

See also:

- [Azure DevOps REST API top parameter in PowerShell script is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345683/azure-devops-rest-api-top-parameter-in-powershell-script-is-not-working)