# What is the continuation token for this API in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, scripting

What is the continuation token in below REST API:

[https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?subjectTypes={subjectTypes}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/users?subjectTypes=%7BsubjectTypes%7D&continuationToken=%7BcontinuationToken%7D&scopeDescriptor=%7BscopeDescriptor%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.1)

I couldn't find it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69346262/736079

Answer (score 2):

In the response of a REST API, normally there is a maximum number limit of items a page can load. If you have too many items need to list, generally it will load the items on multiple pages.

Generally, the **`continuationToken`** to load the second page is on the response body of the first page, and the **`continuationToken`** of the third page is on the second page, and so on.

If you do not see the **`continuationToken`** on a page, typically it means this is the last page or all the items have been loaded on this page.

Comment: I've written an extensive explanation here: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-accessing-apis-with-large-volumes-of-data/